# How do I pass a variable to a function and return the value?

Tags: javascript, return-value

I want to add a number to the variable I pass and return it back to the original function.  So it should log 1 followed by 2, instead of two 1s.

http://jsfiddle.net/E2JnM/

```
function go(){
  var num = 1; 
  console.log(num);
  addNum(num);
  console.log(num);
};

function addNum(num){
  num = num + 1; 
  return num; 
}

go();
```

Comment: Just use the return value, i.e. `num = addNum(num)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the return value since your variable is an int and that is passed by value. When you pass a variable by value to the a function, the result of your changes to `num` won't change once you leave the function scope.

```
function go(){
  var num = 1; 
  console.log(num);

  // Need to store the return value of `addNum` for the result to persist.
  num = addNum(num);
  console.log(num);
};

function addNum(num){
  num = num + 1; 
  return num; 
}

go();
```

Also here is a jsFiddle with the change above: http://jsfiddle.net/LCF4M/1/

Answer (score 3):

num = addNum(num); should do it

Answer (score 2):

You have to assigne return value to the variable

Shor answer:

```
num = addNum(num);
```

Full answer:

```
function go(){
  var num =1; 
  console.log(num);
  num = addNum(num);
  console.log(num);
};

function addNum(num){
  num = num + 1; 
  return num; 
}
go();
```

Using global variable (not recommended) answer:

```
function go(){
  num = 1; // omit var keyword to define global variable
  console.log(num);
  addNum();
  console.log(num);
};

function addNum(){
  num = num + 1; 
}
go();
```